# which dependencies can be suppressed and which cannot ? on a maven dependency check

Tags: java, maven, security, dependencies

How do I know which dependencies I need to suppress? Basically, what makes the difference in the dependencies that are not relevant to those that are?

an example would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly discourage you from asking security related questions here: you are not looking for financial advices on SO, the same applies for security - hire security expert and route all such questions to him.

In regards to [`dependency-check-maven`](https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-maven/) from [OWASP](https://owasp.org/):

1. It is a bad idea to embed it into build lifecycle the way that it fails the build if vulnerable dependencies have been found (`failBuildOnAnyVulnerability`, `failBuildOnCVSS`, etc), otherwise it may suddenly stop the entire SDLC, but developers are not responsible for SEC stuff. Reporting is OK though - just give SEC guys a chance to participate in SDLC via reviewing reports and giving suggestions
2. If `dependency-check-maven` did find nothing it does not mean the application is not vulnerable at the current moment and won't be vulnerable in the future - unfortunately, security is not a `state` but a `process`, that in turn means you need to perform such checks periodically, i.e. either maintain CMDB with detailed information about installed applications and perform checks against that CMDB or use [`dependabot`](https://github.com/dependabot) or other tools.
3. `dependency-check-maven` uses NVD database as a source of information about vulnerabilities, unfortunately neither NVD nor MITRE are actually performing security analysis - they just maintain database, that causes some dumb cases when researcher reports "vulnerability" which is actually not a vulnerability, some examples: [CVE-2021-31684](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-31684), [CVE-2022-26520](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-26520), however, investigating such cases is not a developer responsibility

Answer (score -1):

If you have the time, you can remove all the dependencies from your pom, keeping them aside in a `.bak` file.

Of course, the compilation will fail,
but then you add them back, **one by one**, and only the one Maven build is complaining about their lack.

Then you execute and check that everything in your application is still working well.

That way, you seldom remove two or three dependencies when the project is very old.

Comment: It might be easier to use a version control tool...

Comment: Thank you,
I just began learning about security and the dependency checks, vulnerabilities, and this was one of the things that was hard to comprehend.
so the process would be like... remove dependency, if works, remove another vulnerable dependency, if it does not work, then add the dependency back.

Comment: @JuanVelasquez Just removing a dependency and check if it does not work only applies for applications which you can fully validate their functionality. In real world applications this is most likely not possible. So a better approach is to have a deeper look into what that dependency is really doing and if it can be removed. Sometimes projects are so old that some functionality is now available in recent JDK version.

Answer (score -1):

Each Maven dependency can provide some of transitive dependencies.

Each used dependency in your project is relevant, simply project will not compile without it. Some of dependencies can be needed in runtime by your project.

You can read about [Maven Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) and how to [exclude dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html).

You can also examine output of:

- `mvn dependency:analyze`
- `mvn dependency:tree`

Please familiarize yourself with documentation of [Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html)